# Conversion of NumPy array to Java readable format

Tags: java, arrays, numpy

I am trying to convert few numpy arrays to java readable format. Different arrays may have data types as uint8, float16, float32 etc. How do I accomplish such conversion without changing the size of the array, while it is being stored on the disk.

Comment: What you have tried? Add your code here.

Comment: I don't know what to try, don't have much idea about java. But I would like to   accomplish such conversion in python itself and would like to store them in java readable format, without changing the space it occupies on the disk